# Understand Kotlin Comparison Syntax

Tags: kotlin

**Background:** I am new to kotlin and has some experience in java.

**Problem:**
I am going through the kotlin intellij tutorial to learn about collections and the way to use the `sort*` functions but I am confused about the syntax.

The code written to use the kotlin `sortedByDescending` function :

```
// Return a list of customers, sorted in the descending by number of orders they have made
fun Shop.getCustomersSortedByOrders(): List<Customer> =
        customers.sortedByDescending {
            it.orders.size // I am confused here
        }
```

the definition of kotlin `sortedByDescending` function

```
public inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>.sortedByDescending(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List<T> {
    return sortedWith(compareByDescending(selector))
}
```

To my understanding, the `sortedByDescending` takes a function which input type is T and returns an output in type `Comparable<R>> Iterable<T>`.

1. what does the return type mean? it looks like `R` needs to implement the `Comparable` but also needs to be an `Iteratable` of `T` . Is my understanding correct?
2. if my understanding is right, the how does `it.orders.size` fit into that type? I know `it` in kotlin is used for single params in lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing the different parts of the method signature:

```
public inline fun <T, R : Comparable<R>> 
    Iterable<T>.sortedByDescending(crossinline selector: (T) -> R?): List<T> {
  
  return sortedWith(compareByDescending(selector))
}
```

- **`<T, R : Comparable<R>>`**
  These are the type parameters. The function takes two type parameters: `T`, which can be anything, and `R`, which is restricted by the upper bound `Comparable<R>` (i.e. `R` may only be substituted for a subtype of `Comparable<R>`).
- **`Iterable<T>`**
  This is the type of objects on which the `sortedByDescending()` function can be invoked.
- **`List<T>`**
  This is the return type of the function.

Putting it all together, the `sortedByDescending()` function

- can be invoked on targets of type `Iterable<T>`;
- takes a lambda expression as an argument, which needs to transform a value of type `T` into a value of type `R`, where `R` needs to be `Comparable`;
- returns a result of type `List<T>`.

In this specific case, the list of customers is sorted in descending order by the number of orders per customer (`it.orders.size`).

Comment: aha I misread the `Iterable<T>` as the input params. Silly mistake.

Comment: and how could `it.orders.size` be a comparator?
I am expecting something like `c1, c2 -> c1.orders.size - c2.orders.size`

Comment: It's not a `Comparator`, it's `Comparable`. Most likely an [`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/).

Comment: I understand it should return an `Int` but does it always return a positive number?  I think it should take in two elements so you can compare?

Comment: Take a look at the implementations (or even just the signatures) of `sortedWith()` and `compareByDescending()`. That should clear things up.